# How to use grep to match incomplete file names

Tags: grep, macintosh

I am trying to master various use of grep and this is [my source](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grep-regular-expressions/)
What I don't understand is the section on "how to match single characters", like at all!For example, the author said this:

Let us find all filenames starting with purchase:

`grep 'purchase' demo.txt`

But when I do similar thing in my Mac terminal, the result is not what I expected based on the article.

The terminal said that `demo.txt no such file or directory`
Did I misunderstood what the author was trying to say?

[image]

Comment: Any ideas what do you think *"demo.txt no such file or directory"* is trying to tell you?

Comment: It means what it normally means I suppose. But that doesn’t make sense in the context of the article I cited.or maybe a better question is: how to use grep to search file name that in precise?

Comment: The article doesn't talk about searching a filename, but searching the string "purchase" in a text file named `demo.txt`. Which file exists on the author's computer, but not on yours.

Comment: Admittedly, the sentence "let us search all filenames starting with 'purchase'" can be misleading. Whether the strings are filenames, company names, family names or whatever else is irrelevant.

Comment: for searching file names use `find -iname` (or if you insist in grep `find | grep`) https://linux.die.net/man/1/find

Comment: Please post text as text (not as a picture of text), to comply with accessibility guidelines, and to make it readable. Especially by blind people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author uses a file named `demo.txt` as an example. If you want to follow along, you have to create that file and fill it with

```
foo.txt
... lines removed for brevity ...
purchase.db
purchase1.db
purchase2.db
purchase3.db
purchase.idx
foo2.txt
bar.txt
```

You can create it with a text editor, or on the command line like this:

```
$ cat >demo.txt <<EOF
> foo.txt
... lines removed for brevity ...
> bar.txt
> EOF
```

(the $ and the > at the beginning of each line are shell prompts)

Comment: Thank you so much!I see that I completely misread the author!